# How can I allow for a raw_input of an equation (such as 4x**2-y) so then it can be later evaluated in a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner at python 2.7 and I am trying to write a code to approximate a function given its slope in the form (dy/dx)=f(x,y) using Euler's Method. For the moment I am simply trying to input a function and its values and then evaluate it, before going on to the actual Euler's Method. The code I attempted below returns a syntax error with the equation that I input.
This is the code:

```
function_input=raw_input("(dy/dx) in the form f(x,y)")
x0=float(raw_input("Initial x"))
y0=float(raw_input("Initial y"))
h=float(raw_input("step value"))
def f(x_value,y_value,function):
    x=x_value
    y=y_value
    return eval(function)

print f(x0,y0,function_input)
```

The code worked when I didn't do a raw_input for the function and instead put a given one as a string like so:

```
def f(x_value,y_value,function):
    x=x_value
    y=y_value
    return eval(function)

print f(x0,y0,"x**2-y")
```

Comment: Did you try printing the string, and comparing it to what you expected?  Obviously there must be some difference.  What is it?  Include the incorrect string in your post.

Comment: Yes I printed the variable using:
    
    print function_input

and it printed the string as I expected.
the equation I input was 4x-5y and it returned:

    4x-5y
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax with a carrot underneath the x

(I'm trying to write it as code using the 4 spaces but it won't allow me to)

Comment: Ok, so what did it give you?  You haven't answered my question, so I can't answer yours.

Comment: The point is you have a string that works, `"x**2-y"`.  The string you typed in doesn't work.  Therefore, the string you typed in is different.  So correct the difference.  How can this possibly be so confusing to you?  *Type same string that works and it will behave the same.*  It's that simple.

Comment: The problem is that `4x` is invalid syntax.  It should be `4 * x`.  Therefore, your whole equation should be `4*x - 5*y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `4x` is not a valid input. If you want it to work, your `(dy/dx)` needs to be `4*x**2-y`. You're assuming that it's implicit multiplication, but you need to be explicit in the coefficient of `x`. It works fine otherwise (for your test case).

Comment: Where are you seeing `4x`?  It does not appear anywhere in the post.

Comment: @TomKarzes that was my confusion too. It's in the post title.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yeah, assuming that wasn't a typo, that could cause the problem.

Comment: It works now, feel pretty stupid for such a mistake... But thank you

Comment: @BenjaminK. Don't feel stupid, it's just a mistake and sometimes needs a second pair of eyes (though mine did go off-topic with `h` being involved somehow :P) If you feel that this has solved the problem, I would be grateful for you accepting the answer and closing the question.